# DIY non-professional surveying question: on topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question over on the Home Improvement site:
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5033/diy-easy-and-accurate-small-scale-landscape-survey

It was suggested in a comment that this site might be more appropriate. Is it appropriate to ask a question about the basics of surveying equipment for a non-professional to rent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not, ask away!

Comment: OK, thanks! FYI, here it is: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6911/diy-easy-and-accurate-small-scale-landscape-survey